# How to show that the nonlinear operator I+N is onto?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, nonlinear-system

Is it possible to show that the nonlinear operator $I+N:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is onto, without showing that the nonlinear operator N is contraction? Because we know that if N is a contraction mapping, then it is always true that I+N is onto. But I want without assuming the contraction of N, I+N should be onto.

Comment: But then it may not be true for all $N$, right? If $N$ is a contraction, we know it is true, but the converse need not hold, so we don't know what other $N$ satisfies this condition.

Comment: what about boundedness of N?

Comment: I don't think boundedness is sufficient. For example, what if $N=-I$?